# JPA Entity with DayOfWeek list

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Is it possible to add a `HashSet<DayOfWeek>` to an entity without creating a new table for it? I would like to store it as `json`.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class Test{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private HashSet<DayOfWeek> activeDays;
}
```

Comment: That should be doable with an [ElementCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F6%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html). PS: I'd recomment against using `HashSet<DayOfWeek> activeDays` and instead just declare the field `Set<DayOfWeek> activeDays`. Your persistence framework will choose its own fitting implementation of Set to use here.

Comment: witch version of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` are you using ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa 2.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I tried but I get message: 'Basic' attribute type should not be a container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A collection of simple values can be mapped with an `@ElementCollection`, but this requires a separate table.

For the case of the question, i.e. mapping a set of enumerations to a single column, I like using a bitset - just like Java's `EnumSet` does under the hoods. We map each member of the enum to a boolean with just 1 bit set, e.g.:

| Enum member | boolean |
| --- | --- |
| `MONDAY` | 0000001 |
| `TUESDAY` | 0000010 |
| `WEDNESDAY` | 0000100 |
| ...and so on | 0001000 |

Mapping the enum to the bitset is simply `1 << dayOfWeek.ordinal()`. So a value of e.g. 0000101 means `EnumSet.of(WEDNESDAY, MONDAY)`. Now it is easy to use the bitwise operators of the database to query for membership - e.g. if you want all the `Test` records that contain `TUESDAY`, do:

```sql
-- This is a pseudocode example!!!
-- Various DBs have different ways to express binary constants and bitwise operators
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE activeDays & 0b0000010 <> 0
```

This requires a JPA `AttributeConverter` as follows:

```java
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.util.AbstractCollection;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class DayOfWeekConverter implements AttributeConverter<EnumSet<DayOfWeek>, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(EnumSet<DayOfWeek> value) {
        return value == null ? null : value.stream().mapToInt(this::toBitmap).reduce(0, (aggr, cur) -> aggr | cur);
    }

    private int toBitmap(DayOfWeek d) {
        return 1 << d.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public EnumSet<DayOfWeek> convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null :
                Arrays.stream(DayOfWeek.values())
                        .filter(d -> (toBitmap(d) & dbData) != 0)
                        .collect(
                                () -> EnumSet.noneOf(DayOfWeek.class),
                                AbstractCollection::add,
                                AbstractCollection::addAll
                        );
    }
}
```

...and an annotation on the field as follows - note that I have used the more efficient `EnumSet` for the data type:

```java
@Convert(converter = DayOfWeekConverter.class)
private EnumSet<DayOfWeek> activeDays;
```

You can tweak the converter to store a JSON value or any custom format of the `EnumSet` you can think of (e.g. a string like `"|MONDAY|WEDNESDAY|"` is perfectly possible and queryable e.g. as `activeDays LIKE '%|MONDAY|%'`). I think searching through SQL will be less efficient if you use a string representation, but that is up to you.

Actually, the converter to string as above could be implemented as:

```java
public class DayOfWeekConverter implements AttributeConverter<EnumSet<DayOfWeek>, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(EnumSet<DayOfWeek> value) {
        return value == null ? null : value.stream().map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.joining("|","|","|"));
    }

    @Override
    public EnumSet<DayOfWeek> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null :
                Arrays.stream(DayOfWeek.values())
                        .filter(d -> dbData.contains('|' + d.name() + '|'))
                        .collect(
                                () -> EnumSet.noneOf(DayOfWeek.class),
                                AbstractCollection::add,
                                AbstractCollection::addAll
                        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I wouldn't have come across that. 
Generally it is in the case of `String` that you can use `,` as a hyphen (when you use JPA and don't write a native query). 
Then in `convertToEntityAttribute` just do `return value == null ? null :
                Arrays.stream(dbData.split(",")).map(DayOfWeek::valueOf)
                        .collect(
 () -> EnumSet.noneOf(DayOfWeek.class),
AbstractCollection::add,
 AbstractCollection::addAll);`

Comment: Yeap, that is definitely another way - could be more performant too (maybe worth trying)

Comment: The reason I am including the separator, `"|"`, both at the beginning and at the end of the converted string is to make searches unambiguous. For the specific case of days it is redundant; imagine however an enum containing the values `ERROR` and `NO_ERROR`. If you search with `x LIKE '%ERROR%'`, it will also return records containing only `NO_ERROR`, which is not what you want!