# JPA / OpenJPA: Map integer field from DB table to custom object instead of enum

Tags: java, jpa, orm, openjpa

I use OpenJPA in my Java project. The question is about a non-nullable integer column.

Currently this field is mapped to an `enum` class by the `ordinal` index:

```
@Column(nullable=false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
```

Instead, I'd like to map this db-side integer column to a custom object.

Something like

```
@Column(nullable=false)
@CustomObject( dbtype=java.sql.Types.INTEGER,  // What do we find in the DB table?
               intValue -> MyObjectsRepository.getInstance( intValue ),  // Integer to MyObject
               myObject -> myObject.getIntValue() )  // MyObject to Integer
```

Does this exist?

In the best case, there is a JPA-way (implementation agnostic). But if there's only an OpenJPA-only trick, that would help me as well.

Comment: As a side comment, don't use the ordinal because if the constants are re-arranged or removed then this will break.

Comment: You can use a standard JPA `AttributeConverter` - see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77126279/jpa-entity-with-dayofweek-list/77127007#77127007). But in your case you may even convert the value in the getter/setter.